# WPF - Data Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF. As far as I understand, data bound controls automatically update when the source data is changed. Why would someone change the UI through data rather than manipulating it directly? I mean, if I want to change the text of a Label, why would I choose to change its bound data rather than its Text property directly?

Then you might ask why I bound it to a data source in the first place. But it seems to be the only solution in order to instantiate the XAML template with data coming from the server. That way, I don't have to write imperative code in the code behind for the initial rendering of the view. But when I want to update it, I will have to do it via code anyway, even I use data binding.

So the question basically is, why change the view model rather than changing the view itself?

Comment: Because everything sucks a whole lot less when you can keep the "model" code separate from the UI code. This was instantly obvious to me when I first saw it after years of MFC and winforms. I sang Hallelujah. Such a relief.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I totally agree on seperating the business model from the UI code but it is the view model that we are updating anyway. I actually understand the benefits of one-time binding, which is binding of the view model in the page initialization phase. But when it comes to updating the view, I cannot understand the benefit of changing the view model rather than the view itself.

Comment: A lot of very experienced and very smart professionals see profound value in it. Of course, the same is true of LISP -- but then that's why I don't get into arguments about the value of LISP. Had I time to learn it, I'd probably see the value they do. I draw the line at tcl, though. Ugh.

Comment: Why so many downvotes.. This question seems to be quite reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is probably about why we should use MVVM and data binding. So its like asking why not `TextBox.Text="HelloWorld"` rather than `TextBox.Text="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty"`.

Since I am working in WPF/MVVM from the last 4 years, I can tell you the answer in short. The approach you're saying here is best suited for a small single page application. Say you have a single page application with 3 textboxes. You need to get the textbox values from server. What you will do is simply place 3 textboxes in your view. In code behind ie xaml.cs you can write,

```
TextBox1.Text = SomeServerCallOrDbCall.GetData1();
TextBox2.Text = SomeServerCallOrDbCall.GetData1();
TextBox3.Text = SomeServerCallOrDbCall.GetData1();
```

Consider a large application. You need to display 100's of fields in the view. You need to fetch data from multiple servers and services. You need to navigate between views and exchange data between views, services or with databases. At this time, this so called databinding/MVVM approach will help a lot. It will help you in separation of concerns. If you write all these code in code behind(ie xaml.cs), then your code will become cumbersome and your code reusability, readability and maintainability will be very poor. If you want to change a field, or test a part of the application, it will be very difficult to search for the line of code in a very vast code behind. So you use MVVM. Also many people can work in a single project at the same time. While one developer is designing the view, some other developer could create the view model. This makes testing easy too. Also MVVM enables you to achieve `TwoWay Binding` easily. Hence when you change your textbox text, it is automatically updated in the ViewModel property and this in turn can be used to update the data in the database or service.

Hence you can follow this approach :

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding ViewModelProperty1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Text="{Binding ViewModelProperty2, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox3" Text="{Binding ViewModelProperty3, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**Benefits of MVVM model in a nutshell :**

> 1. Maintanability
> 2. Readability
> 3. Reusability
> 4. Better testability
> 5. Good separation of concern
> 6. Less code duplication
> 7. Two way data binding

Comment: I actually understand the benefits of one-time binding, which is binding of the data in the page initialization phase. But when it comes to updating the view, I cannot understand the benefit of changing the view model rather than the view itself.

Comment: That is what I tried to explain in my answer. Did you read it? It's possible to update the view for a small application/ single page application. If you want to update the service or database synchronously while typing text in a textbox or any such scenario, 2 way binding will be very handy. If you're not following MVVM, then you want to track the text changed event and then update db or service, which can include many lines of extra code. But in MVVM, it will be very neat and clean.

Answer (score 0):

you wanna code like

view.xaml

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txtName"/>
```

view.xaml.cs

```
  txtName.Text = "Bob";
  MyServiceCall(txtName.Text);
```

thats fine, but i dont like it.

i prefer MVVM: (i dont care about the view in my viewmodel)

view.xaml

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

viewmodel

```
  Name = "Bob";

  MyServiceCall(Name);
```